# ForeignKeyConstraintError [SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError]: insert or update on table "avatars" violates foreign key constraint

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, psql

I have two tables and the username is called something different, but they're connected via foreign keys:
table users has a column username
table avatars has a column ownerUsername

I'm stuck on this foreign key problem and updating a record. I recently remade the foreign keys to have UPDATE CASCADE, but I still get this error when trying to update:

ForeignKeyConstraintError [SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError]: insert or update on table "avatars" violates foreign key constraint "User_OwnerUsername_fk"

It also says this further below:

detail: Key (ownerUsername)=(theSunBurn) is not present in table "users"

I'm not sure what's the problem here. is it because the 'username' field in the users table is called 'ownerUsername' in the avatars table? Or is it because i'm updating the ownerUsername to 'theSunBurn' in the avatars table, but in the users table it's still the old user name? Also, when updating fields with foreign keys, am I supposed to update both tables at once somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, the foreign key used is not an Id but a mutable key that is a 'user name'.
The issue as you asked isnt with the name of the column in the 'avatars' table. The issue is when we update a foreign key with a value(that is updated ownerUsername to 'theSunBurn') that is not present as a primary key, it is show the error you recieved.

You can either use ID instead of UserName as a foreign key
OR
Whenever you want to update in avatars, first create an entry (if not already present) in users

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. My issue is, I want to refer to 'username' in the 'users' table, not the id there. I want to be able to access the user's username from users when needed, but I also want the username as a field within 'avatars' so that on another page, I only need to do an SQL query for the avatar and I'll receive the accurate username as well. Should I be using a join for this instead?

Comment: Yes, you are right. A join is the way to go. Your username resides in users table and that all right. You can use userId as a foreign key in avatars table. So whenever you want to edit username, you can edit directly in users table and it will be reflected everywhere it is referenced(in this case avatars table)

Comment: Great, this makes sense! Thanks for the answers.

Comment: A few related questions: 
1. Are foreign keys typically used to refer to primary keys in other tables and is it uncommon to have it refer to other columns? 
2. I'm going to need to make a new field in 'avatars' now for userId. I already have over 200 users, is there a way to automatically assign their id to my new userId field in 'avatars'?

Comment: To answer your questions 1. Yes 2. You'll have to migrate the data into avatars for the existing entries in 'Avatars'. If the existing column of username has proper entries then you can write an update query on avatars table using subquery with username of users = username of avatars as the update condition

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that i was using a primary key from a table whose record was not present in that table. So i created new entry and then used it and was fixed.